# I want to get the value of the span (checkout_date)

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

This is my code which allows the user to enter the following details for a hotel booking reservation:

- phone number
- number of rooms
- number of nights
- whether they require breakfast or not
- booking date

The checkout date outputs when the user enters the booking date and the number of nights. However, I'm trying to update my database whenever the user clicks book and the checkout date saves in the database.

Jquery code for the checkout date to happen and for the total cost for the stay:

```
<style>
#checkout_date,
#total_price {
color: red;
}
</style>  

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date, #NumberOfNights').on("change", updateCheckout);

    $('#price, #NumberOfNights, #NumberOfRooms').on("change", updateTotalPrice);

    function updateCheckout() {
        var bookingDate = $('#date').val();
        var numOfNights = $('#NumberOfNights').val();
        if (bookingDate != '' && numOfNights != '') {
            var new_date = moment(bookingDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(numOfNights, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            $('#checkout_date').text(new_date);
        } else {
            $('#checkout_date').text('N/A');
        }
    }

    function updateTotalPrice() {
        var price = $('#price').val();
        var numOfNights = $('#NumberOfNights').val();
        var NumberOfRooms = $('#NumberOfRooms').val();
        if (price != '' && numOfNights != '' && NumberOfRooms != '') {
            var total_price = +price * +numOfNights * +NumberOfRooms;
            $('#total_price').text('£' + total_price);
            } else {
                $('#total_price').text('N/A');
        }
    }

});
</script>
```

Html code for the booking details to be entered;

```
<body>

  <form action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Personal Details: </legend>
      <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" required placeholder="Please enter in your phone number" pattern="[0-9]{4}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}" title="Please enter in a phone number in this format:#### ### ###">
      <select name="country" required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="US">US</option>
        <option value="UK">UK</option>
        <option value="AUS">AUS</option>

      </select>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Booking Details: </legend>
      <label for="date">Booking date: </label>
      <input id="date" type="date" name="date" min="2017-01-04">
      <label for="numberOfRooms">Number of Rooms:</label>
      <input id="NumberOfRooms" type="number" name="numberOfRooms" min="1" max="4">
      <label for="numberOfNights">Number of Nights:</label>
      <input id="NumberOfNights" type="number" name="numberOfNights" min="1" max="60">
      <input id="price" value="<?php echo($price['Hotel_price']); ?>" type="number" hidden="hidden" min="0">
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Checkout Date:</label>
      <span id="checkout_date"> N/A</span>
      <p>Do you require breakfast?</p>
      <label for="yesBreakfast">Yes:</label>
      <input id="yesBreakfast" type="radio" name="meals" value="yesBreakfast">
      <label for="noBreakfast">No:</label>
      <input id="noBreakfast" type="radio" name="meals" value="noBreakfast">
      <br>
      <!--<label for="balcony">Do you require a balcony?</label><input id="balcony" type="checkbox" name="balcony" value="yes" checked>-->
      <br>

      <label>Total Price:</label>
      <span id="total_price"> N/A</span>
      <br><br>
      <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
```

The structure of the database table which is called book:

```
 id(int 11)
 username(varchar 30)
 hotel_id(int 11)
 phone(varchar 50)
 date(datetime)
 num_nights(int 60)
 num_nights(int 4)
 checkout(date)
```

code for inserting in the DB

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $UserName = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $Phone = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['phone']);
    $Date = mysqli_real_escape_string  ($con, $_POST['date']);
    $NumNights = mysqli_real_escape_string  ($con, $_POST['numberOfNights']);
    $NumberRooms = mysqli_real_escape_string  ($con, $_POST['numberOfRooms']);
    $Check_out =  mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['check_outdate']);

    $sql ="INSERT INTO book (username, phone,date,num_nights, num_rooms, hotel_id, check_out) VALUES('" . $UserName . "', '" . $Phone . "', '" . $Date . "' , '" . $NumNights . "' , '" . $NumberRooms . "', '" . $id . "', '". $Check_out."')";



    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
        echo("sucess");
    } else {
        echo("failed");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? With getting the value of `#checkout_date`?

Comment: yes with the checkout_date

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, it can be done this way: `$('#checkout_date').text()` - this will fetch the _current_ text value of that span.

Comment: You are providing way more code and information than necessary. Getting the value of a span is trivial. Just look at @Optimae's comment. Why are you sharing database structure information??? Where is the actual span html code, and how would you like to access it (jquery? php?).

Comment: how can i use this value in php? Since i want to insert it in my database

Comment: Are you asking how to insert just that value or all of the values in the form?

Comment: @Andrew i want to access it by php because i want to insert it in my database. I included my database structure because i wanted to insert the value

Comment: @Optimae just that value. The rest are working fine...

Comment: It's hard to know what you're having trouble with exactly. What error do you get when trying to save checkout_date in the database? Can you share the PHP code responsible for inserting it into the DB and any errors that you're receiving? If you're not receiving any errors and it's not saving then make sure you've turned errors on in php.ini

Comment: Access the values in php using the $_POST superglobal. As your action is empty it will post to the same page that generates the form. So either test if it's a post above the form and handle submit instead or add an action to a different page.

Comment: @Optimae i can't seem to put my DB insert code in the code above... CAn you see it?

Comment: @amir I can't see it, try maybe via https://pastebin.com/? It should let you edit the comment though.

Comment: @Optimae I have edited the code and tried to paste it 5 times but it doesn't work

Comment: @Optimae Its working now. CAn you see it now

Comment: Soem sensible code formatting REALLY HELPS us read the code and more importantly **you debug it**

Comment: @amir What happens when you run the query?

Comment: I get this error;    Notice: Undefined index: checkout_date in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hotel\booknow.php on line 34
sucess

Comment: anyone willing to help please :(

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an `Undefined index` error with your `checkout_date` date is because PHP's `$_POST` method can only read from **inputs** that have a **name**.

In order to get your script working you have a couple of options:

### 1. Use AJAX

AJAX will give you much greater flexibility as you can select any element via jQuery, store them in variables and then submit. You won't be limited to just `input` fields the way you are with PHP forms.

A good starting point is to read the official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

### 2. Use a styled, *readonly* input field

In your HTML:

Change your `<span id="checkout_date">N/A</span>` to `<input id="checkout_date" name="checkout_date" readonly>`

Then update your jQuery methods:

Change `$('#checkout_date').text(new_date)` to `$('#checkout_date').val(new_date)` because that's how you set the value of an input field.

This will give you an input field that the user cannot edit. You can then style it via CSS so that it doesn't look like an input field, for example you could make it look the same way your span currently does.

### 3. Use a hidden input field AND the span

In your HTML:

Create an input field and add the `hidden` attribute to it, while keeping the span. Make sure the ID of the input and the span are different, as you'll need to apply different jQuery methods to them. Example:

```
<input id="checkout_date_input" name="checkout_date" hidden>
<span id="checkout_date_span">N/A</span>
```

In your jQuery:

```
$('#checkout_date_span').text(new_date);
$('#checkout_date_input').val(new_date);
```

Summary

Any of the above methods will let you get your checkout date via

`$checkoutDate = $_POST['checkout_date']`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, It still didn't work... It doesn't show the checkout date anymore and the it doesn't update in the DB. Also, can you give me an example of an ajax in this scenario?

Comment: What did you change in your original code and what error message are you getting? Can you share your new code via https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://pastebin.com/?

Comment: if you have looked at the link that I have sent and have a solution, please message here. Thanks!